# Проблемы с доступом к iframe

Tags: javascript, html, отладка

Есть один магический iframe c `id="ifr"`. Высота содержимого этого iframe может занять как 50px, так и 500px — зависит от расширения экрана. Определяется это следующем способом:

```
document.getElementById('ifr').contentDocument.height
```

Для того, чтобы iframe сам себе подбирал высоту на основе внутренностей, я написал вот такой код:

```
document.getElementById('ifr').style.height = document.getElementById('ifr').contentDocument.height + 'px';
```

Вбиваю в консоль Chrome — всё ок.

Потом вставляю код в HTML страницу. Получилось так:

```
<iframe id="ifr" src="inpup.html"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('ifr').style.height = document.getElementById('ifr').contentDocument.height + 'px';
    </script>
</iframe>
```

Размер iframe-а изменятся не хочет.

Затем попробовал почти то же самое, только на `onload`:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('ifr').style.height = document.getElementById('ifr').contentDocument.height + 'px';">
```

Не помогло.

Почему код с консоли работает, а нормально встроенный в страницу код — нет? Как это исправить?

**P. S.** Мне надо встроить код в HTML. Не надо заставлять пользователей вводить какую-то непонятную строчку в какую-то непонятную консоль хрома.

**P. P. S.** И основная страница, и iframe с одного домена.

Comment: Как-то не очень сочетается то, что вы хотите изменять ширину iframe и установка значения height. Вы ничего не перепутали?

Comment: Потому что iframe загружается позже события onload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переместите код в `onload`. [@KaZaца](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10548/kaza%D1%86%D0%B0) всё правильно сказал:

> Потому что iframe загружается позже события onload.